# How to prevent Silverfish from melding into blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In normal Minecaft with no gamerules changed, silverfish have the capability to meld with existing stone, stone brick or cobble to turn that block into an egg block.

If I were to use silverfish in an adventure map but prevent silverfish from "melding" back into the blocks, how would I do this? (I've already tried gamerule mobGriefing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

silver fish can't mend into monster eggs (like the block). Ive tried this and it works, so hope this helps! so sorry if for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: But then if you attack, all already monster eggs will get destroyed and all silvefish will attack you. :) Probably the thing is to not lose the building.

Comment: Silver can't go into monster eggs because they _are already_ in the monster eggs.  This really doesn't help.

Comment: _Actually_, I think this is better than saying it isn't possible. It's certainly a feasible solution in a situation where the silverfish won't get hit.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to prevent silverfish from entering blocks (although this seems to me that it should be prevented by `mobGriefing`, maybe you should suggest it?). I don't know if this is suitable, but a potential solution is to set the difficulty to peaceful. Then, if silverfish did spawn they would instantly de-spawn again.

Comment: Then again, it's supposed to be a dungeon-style mob fighting game. So peaceful wouldn't do. Where would I suggest the feature?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but for anyone having the same issue you can use stairs and slabs since they cannot *meld* into them and they look like stone and bricks

Answer (score 0):

If you are making an adventure map then the simplest way to do this is definitely use monster egg blocks, as long as it is in adventure mode and mob griefing is off the silverfish will not break out.

**The Better Way** would be to layer slabs, for instance stone bricks or stone, or even cobble. This gives the same appearance as a full block, but the silverfish do not count this as a block they can burrow into, making it the best way to stop them burrowing.